# Drracket: Create a function that will return a sorted list given a comparer using bubble sort

Tags: sorting, racket

This is what I have to sort strings:

```
;create a function that checks if a list of strings is sorted
(define (stringCmpr l)
         (if (<= (length l) 1)
            true
            (and (string<=? (car l) (cadr l))(stringCmpr (cdr l))
                 )
            )
  )
;Create a funciton that checks if a list of numbers is sorted
(define (numCmpr l)
         (if (<= (length l) 1)
            true
            (and (<= (car l) (cadr l)) (numCmpr (cdr l))
                 )
            )
  )
;create function that checks whether a list containes numbers of 
strings checks if the list is sorted
(define (is-sorted? l)
         (if (number? (car l))
            (numCmpr l)
            (stringCmpr l)
            )
  )
    (define (bubble-pass lst)
      (cond
        ((empty? lst) lst)
        ((= (length lst) 1) lst)
        ((and (= (length lst) 2) (string>? (first lst) (second lst))) 
(list 
    (second lst) (first lst)))
        ((and (= (length lst) 2) (string<? (first lst) (second lst))) 
lst)
        ((string>? (first lst) (second lst))
         (append
          (list (second lst))
          (bubble-pass (append (list (first lst)) (rest (rest lst))))
          )
         )
        (else
         (append (list (first lst) (second lst)) (bubble-pass (rest 
(rest lst))))
         )
        )
      )

(define (string-bubble-sort lst)
  (if (is-sorted? lst)
      lst
      (string-bubble-sort (bubble-pass last))
      )
  )
```

This works for sorting strings in order from A-Z

This is what I have so far for the general sort (func represents the comparer: <, > =, string<?, etc):

```
;create a function that checks if a list of strings is sorted
(define (gen-stringCmpr l func)
         (if (<= (length l) 1)
            true
            (and (func (car l) (cadr l))(gen-stringCmpr (cdr l) func)
                 )
             )
  )
;Create a funciton that checks if a list of numbers is sorted
(define (gen-numCmpr l func)
         (if (<= (length l) 1)
            true
            (and (func (car l) (cadr l)) (gen-numCmpr (cdr l) func)
                 )
            )
  )
;create funciton that checks whether a list contains numbers or 
strings checks if the list is sorted
(define (general-sorted? l func)
         (if (number? (car l))
            (gen-numCmpr l func)
            (gen-stringCmpr l func)
            )
  )
; Purpose: Create a function that bubble sorts a list given a 
; comparison function

;Signature:
; list function-> list

;Examples:
(check-expect (general-bubble-sort (list "B" "A" "C") string<?) (list 
"A" "B" "C"))
(check-expect (general-bubble-sort (list "B" "A" "C") string>?) (list 
"C" "B" "A"))
(check-expect (general-bubble-sort (list 6 4 5) <) (list 4 5 6))
(check-expect (general-bubble-sort (list 2 3 1) >) (list 3 2 1))

Stub:
(define (general-bubble-sort lst func) '( "spinach")

 Template:

Code:

(define (general-bubble-pass lst func)
  (cond
    ((empty? lst) last)
    ((= (length lst) 1) last)
    ((and (= (length lst) 2) (equal? (func (first lst) (second lst)) 
false)) (list (second lst) (first lst)))
    ((and (= (length lst) 2) (func (first lst) (second lst))) last)
    ((equal? (func (first lst) (second lst)) false)
     (append
      (list (second last))
      (general-bubble-pass (append (list (first lst)) (rest (rest 
lst))) func)
      )
     )
    (else
     (append (list (first lst) (second lst)) (general-bubble-pass 
(rest (rest lst)) func))
     )
    )
  )

(define (general-bubble-sort lst func)
  (if (general-sorted? lst func)
      lst
      (general-bubble-sort (general-bubble-pass lst func) func)
      )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't properly using your abstractions here because of overly permissive signatures. Technically you want your final bubble sort to work like this:

```
; general-bubble-sort: (X) [List-of X] [X X -> Boolean] -> [List-of X]
```

By constraining the types of what we take in and telling users how they should use it, we eliminate the checking we need to do in `general-sorted?`. We just know that we have to pass the correct function to it, otherwise it is the users fault for not passing the correct function. You can also abstract more of your code between your two functions. Like this:

```
(define (general-sorted? l func)
  (or (<= (length l) 1) (and (func (car l) (cadr l)) (general-sorted? (cdr l)))))
```

Your second function has a lot going on in it, lets combine some of the cases and also not use `(equal? x boolean)`. That is bad practice. Instead we should use a boolean expression to get us `true` when appropriate. We should also make use of accumulators here as it clearly says what piece of data we are keeping track of as we are recurring down:

```
(define (general-bubble-pass lst func)
  (local [(define (general-bubble-pass-acc lst bubble)
            (cond
              [(empty? lst) (list bubble)]
              [(not (func (first lst) bubble)) (cons bubble (general-bubble-pass-acc (rest lst) (first lst)))]
              [else (cons (first lst) (general-bubble-pass-acc (rest lst) bubble))]))]
    (if (<= (length lst) 1) lst (general-bubble-pass-acc (rest lst) (first lst)))))
```

Your final bubble sort function doesn't change.